# How I define which button onclick from inside a loop

Tags: javascript

any superior can help me to solve the below question. where my script wrong.
My question is, how I get a value from inside the loop when a button and the button also inside the loop too.
Thanks a lot

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var btn = document.getElementsByid("button");

  for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByid("button").length; i++) {
    
    /* my problem in here. How I define which one of the button
    onclick then get value from the <input type=""hidden"> */
    btn[i].onclick = function() {
    
      var hd1 = $("#hidden1"+i).val();
      
      $.get('try.php', {
        sendResult: hd1
      }, function(data) {
        $('#returnResult').html(data);
      });
      
    };
  };
});
```

```html
<!-- I want sending one of the value from '$arrayValue'. -->
<?php
  $arrayValue = array(a, b, c);

  foreach($arrayValue as $eachResult) {

    echo '
      <input type="hidden" id="hidden1" value="'.$eachResult["arrayValue"].'">
    
      <button type="button" id="button"></button>
  ';}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.prev().val()`. and `.getElementsByid("button")` is not valid it should be `.getElementsByTagName("button")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

  for(var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {

    /* my problem in here. How I define which one of the button
    onclick then get value from the <input type=""hidden"> */
    btn[i].onclick = function() {

      var hd1 = $("#hidden1" + i).val();
      console.log($(this).prev().val())
      $.get('try.php', {
        sendResult: hd1
      }, function(data) {
        $('#returnResult').html(data);
      });

    };
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden1" value="hidden value 1">
<button type="button" id="button">btn1</button>

<input type="hidden" id="hidden1" value="hidden value 2">
<button type="button" id="button">btn2</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for answer my question, but still cannot work for my script. I change to use class and use getElementFromClassName, but still only can get the last value from loop. Thank You